# Skydiving problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, drag

Why does the velocity of a skydiver become constant again after opening the parachute? If by net F= ma, we will have net F smaller than 0 as the air resistance is increased greatly and the weight remains unchanged. Why does the acceleration becomes 0 again after decelerating?

Answer (score 4):

There are two forces acting on the skydiver.

1. The force ($mg$) due to the weight of the skydiver pulling him towards earth.
2. The drag force ($-kv$) offered by the air as resistance to his motion. This force is in opposite direction to his velocity i.e. upwards (therefore negative).

Let's take the downward direction to be positive. Then net force is

$$F = mg - kv$$

$k$ is just a viscosity constant.

Equate $F$ with $ma$:

$$ma = mg - kv$$

Now you can intuitively see, that $mg$ is just a constant acceleration in the beginning. But as the parachute tries to speed up, the $kv$ factor increases in magnitude until it just equals $mg$. At that point, acceleration becomes zero. Now onwards the velocity will not change (zero acceleration).

This value of velocity is called terminal velocity.

PS: Have a look at the very relevant comments made by some people about what exactly is the effect of the parachute opening. In brief: The above discussion is valid whether the parachute is open or not(every object traveling through a viscous fluid experiences drag). The effect of opening the parachute will only *increase* the magnitude of drag ie the constant k(which is a function of the size and shape of the body) will change.

Comment: Just a helpful note to the one who asked the question:  This is the exact same thing that happens when they reach terminal velocity _before_ they release the parachute.  $k$ changes because the parachute increases drag, that is why this is all induced again.

Comment: @Steeven, thanks for taking the time to edit. It looks much better now. I am guilty that I am still not used to the symbolic formatting techniques and did not take the time to write it out carefully.

Comment: In addition to @JMac's comment: When the parachute opens, it can be considered as a change in $k$ - or it can be considered as just *another, extra* drag force with $k_{parachute}v$ that must be subtracted as well, $$ma=mg-k_{person}v-k_{parachute}v$$

Comment: @A.Melkani You are welcome, and no worries. If you are interested, click the edit button and see how \$...\$ symbols make math formatting.

Comment: I think I'll just add a line in the post to look at the comments. It is easy to enough to understand from the comments itself IMO.

Comment: But I don't understand why does the parachute try to speed up after opening, shouldn't it slow down as the air resistance is greatly increased? This is what I'm thinking: As it slows down,  f also decreases, until they balance again, reaching terminal velocity. If f continues to increase, f will be more and more greater than mg and they won't balance. Sorry for not being able to understand your explanation.

Comment: Look, as the body is falling it has either already attained terminal velocity(zero net force). Or it is falling with a non-zero net force which implies non-zero acceleration which implies increasing velocity which will decrease the force experienced. This feedback cycle will go on until it reaches terminal velocity or something else such as the opening of the parachute takes place.

Comment: Now let us say the parachute is opened. This will increase the value of $k$. Calculate the new net force. If it is negative the person experiences a jerk upwards. If it is zero or positive the same scenario as in the previous comment applies.